# Postgres function to split word to arrays with extra logic

Tags: regex, postgresql

I've been playing around on psql and splitting a name in to an array, so for example:

```sql
select string_to_array('joseph jones', ' ');
string_to_array 
-----------------
{joseph,jones}
```

This works exactly as I expected.

However, my dataset contains a lot of surnames that have a preceding 'o'.

```
select string_to_array('joseph o carroll', ' ');
string_to_array 
-----------------
{joseph,o,carroll}
```

Is there any way I can add some extra logic so that if a word is preceded by a ' o ' then it gets bundled in to the following word?

So `joseph o carroll` would return `{joseph,o carroll}`

Comment: Maybe a regex and `regexp_split_to_array` could do that.

Comment: So far I have ```select regexp_split_to_array('joseph o jones','(\s+)');``` but still trying to figure out how to exclude the ```o ``` from the split

Comment: Ok, so I now have this ```select regexp_split_to_array('joseph o jones','(?<!o)(\s+)');``` which nearly solves my problem but for some reason adds quotation marks around ```o jones```

Comment: The quotes are normal because the result is an array, and if an array element contains a space it will be quoted when the array is displayed. If you access the individual elements, the quotes won't be there, e.g. `select unnest(regexp_split_to_array(..))`

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From playing around with regex, I think I have found a solution:

`select regexp_split_to_array('joseph o jones','(?<!o)(\s+)');`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a mere `(?<!o)\s+`, try it against `romeo bones`. As first name ends in `o`, the expression does not match.

Use

```
select regexp_split_to_array('joseph o jones','(?<!\yo)\s+');
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \y                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    o                        'o'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```